# Database Triggers: On Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

This is a simple example.

I want to insert data in `Table1 (Name, Age, Sex)`. This table has an automatically increasing `serial#`(int) on insertion of data.

I want to put a trigger on `Table1 insert`, so that after inserting data, it picks up the `serial#`(int) from `Table1` and puts `Serial#` and `Name` to `Table2` and `Serial#` and `some other data` in `Table3`.

Is it possible via triggers?

or, should I pick (last) Serial from `table1` and call insert on other tables by increasing it manually, in same `SP` I used to insert in `Table1`?

Which approach is better?

EDIT 1:
Suppose table:

```
Serial | UID | Name | Age | Sex | DateTimeStamp
(int | uniqueidentifier | nvarchar | smallint | nchar | DateTime )
```

Default `NewID()` and Default `GetDate()` as `UID` and `DateTimeStamp`, would `INSERTED` table have Datetime-Of-Insertion in DatetimeStamp field? Meaning, I originally didn't enter any of Serial, GUID or DatetimeStamp, will they occur in INSERTED table?

EDIT 2:
Can you point me towards good books/articles on triggers. I read mastering SQL server 2005, didn't get much out of it. Thanks!

Comment: **YES** - your `INSERTED` table **will have** those values !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can do this with a trigger - something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Table1_INSERT
ON dbo.Table1 AFTER INSERT 
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(SerialNo, Name)
      SELECT SerialNo, Name
      FROM Inserted

   INSERT INTO dbo.Table3(SomeOtherCol)
      SELECT SomeOtherCol
      FROM Inserted
END
```

or whatever it is you need to do here....

It's important to understand that the trigger will be called **once per statement** - not once per row inserted. So if you have a statement that inserts 10 rows, your trigger gets called **once**, and the pseudo-table `Inserted` will contain those 10 rows that have been inserted in the statement.

Comment: so, T1 will have 10 rows, INSERTED will have ten rows, but T2 and T3 won't? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @AnubhavSaini: YES, YES and NO. Yes, `Table1` will have 10 rows, and as such, `Inserted` will have 10 rows. You need to take that into account, e.g. you need to **know that** and program accordingly (lots of devs always assume there's only one row in `Inserted`). And NO - with my code above, `Table2` and `Table3` will **also** get 10 new rows!

Comment: @marc_s just to be clear, the trigger is called once per statement, not once per batch (unless, as may be the case, the batch is only one statement)

Comment: @RalphShillington: sorry - yes, you're right - once per statement. Most important: not once per row! That's the "killer" for lots of folks who always assume `Inserted` is only a single row and do a `SELECT FROM Inserted.....` and fail with multiple rows

Comment: @marc_s, each time inserting in Table1 will insert all rows from Inserted into Table2 (INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(SerialNo, Name)
      SELECT SerialNo, Name
      FROM Inserted), this can not be acceptable!

Comment: @Md.EliasHossain : why not?? You insert **those rows** that we inserted in the last statement - that's what the original question was asking for! The `Inserted` pseudo table just holds those rows that were inserted into the `Table1` in the last statement - **NOT** all rows of `Table1` !!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible with triggers.

When you use an `INSERT` trigger, you have access to the [`INSERTED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) logical table that represents the row to be inserted, with the value of the new ID it in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by trigger, but keep in mind that TRIGGER doesn't take any input and doesn't provide any output, so you only can collect your desired data by querying in the trigger, however to satisfy insertion into your Table2 and Table3

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_YourDesiredTriggerName ON Table1
 FOR INSERT
 AS
 BEGIN
    -- Inserting data to Table2
INSERT INTO Table2( Serial, Name) 
   SELECT i.Serial, i.Name 
       FROM Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Inserted AS i ON t1.Serial = i.Serial
       AND i.Serial NOT IN  ( SELECT t2.Serial FROM Table2 AS t2 )

    -- Inserting data to Table3     
INSERT INTO Table3( Serial, OtherData)  -- select from other table
   SELECT i.Serial, OtherData
       FROM OtherTable AS ot INNER JOIN Inserted AS i ON ot.Serial = i.Serial
       AND i.Serial NOT IN ( SELECT t3.Serial FROM Table3 AS t3 )
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control over the source of the insert then use a trigger.  If you do have control over the source of the inserts then you can modify your insert process to also add the secondary table rows.

Will you also have control over future inserts?  What if another insert gets created for this table?  If you use a trigger then the secondary inserts would also get handled automatically.  If not then the second insert process could possibly leave out the secondary inserts.  Maybe that would be good or bad depending on your application.